# cache storage in Excel Custom Function

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, custom-functions-excel, excel-web-addins

I want to store my searched values in key and pair in excel custom function. and when I search again with the same value it should return from the cache storage. How can I do that?

When I use office runtime storage it shows me error that is "wrong data type".
Except officeruntime storage is there any other way to storage the value in cache storage?

Comment: What code do you use for storing data? Could you be more specific?

Comment: I want to set the data which can be accessible in the custom function of excel and taskpane as well as.

Comment: It seems you have already tried something, what is your code then?